# Comment exprimer ou traduire la technique de « catch and kill » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

Dans un texte on peut lire que :

> AMI, the owner of the National Enquirer, led by David Pecker, recently
>   entered into an immunity deal with the Department of Justice related
>   to their role in the so-called “**Catch and Kill**” process on behalf
>   of President Trump and his election campaign. Mr. Pecker and his
>   company have also been investigated for various actions they’ve taken
>   on behalf of the Saudi Government.
>
> [ [*No thank you, Mr. Pecker*](https://medium.com/@jeffreypbezos/no-thank-you-mr-pecker-146e3922310f), de Jeff Bezos, sur *Medium*, 7 février
>   2019 ]

La technique de [*catch and kill*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_and_kill) consiste en l'achat des « exclusive rights to a story without the intention of publishing it, in effect silencing the seller » (Wikipédia, article *Catch and kill*, cc by-sa 3.0) [ ...des droits exclusifs de publier une nouvelle sans l'intention réelle de la diffuser, en pratique à en réduire au silence son auteur. — ma traduction ].

J'ai vérifié si le terme de pêche *catch and release* ([*pêche avec remise à l'eau des prises*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18046460) ; [*pêcher-relâcher*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26539345)) était d'un quelconque secours  : pas vraiment.

---

- Peut-on identifier une locution (ou combinaison de termes ou locutions) comparable qui serait utile en français ou traduire en faisant attention de ne pas empiéter sur la terminologie existante (cohérence) ?

Comment: *Kill* est certainement *étouffer* ici. Pour *catch*, je ne vois pas autre chose qu'une périphrase.

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'y ai pas beaucoup réfléchi, parfois l'anglais est très usuel et le français peut être très technique. J'ai jeté un coup d’œil du côté de trucs comme _patent troll_ par exemple pour essayer de trouver une forme d'inspiration ou des mots composés contenant une préposition avec l'idée de _soustraire_ etc. Je ne sais pas vraiment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avec des termes moins usuels (commerce/édition, droit, informatique etc.) que ceux de la langue source :

> acquisition-[mise hors cours](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18086996)/[commerce](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=HORS%20COMMERCE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)
>   acquisition-[obfuscation](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870389)/[occultation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/occultation)

Sans le trait d'union au long avec « (vieilli : [pour](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1041))/aux fins d(e)' » (*acquisition aux fins de mise hors commerce*). L'emploi du terme [acquisition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acquisition), (techniquement différent, et possiblement moins usuel qu'achat), et du trait d'union permettent à mon avis de ne pas empiéter sur l'emploi terminologique typique du terme associé.

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que « chapeauter » tel que défini au [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1972004760;) ou de façon légèrement plus précise au [Larousse](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chapeauter/14676?q=chapeauter#14549) puisse remplir le rôle d'un terme correspondant à « catch » ; le résultat de l'action de « to catch » est un emprisonnement, une mise à la merci d'un pouvoir exerçant un contrôle important sur ce qui a été « attrapé » et ce résultat est bien ce qu'exprime le verbe « chapeauter ». Je ne suis pas conscient d'une acception de ce dernier à l'effet de « amener à l'état d'être chapeauté ». Je choisis ce terme plutôt que son synonyme « coiffer » parce qu'il bénéficie d'une plus grande spécificité, c'est à dire que l'on l'identifie plus distinctement en association avec ce contexte de « tutelle ».

> (TLFi) B. Au fig.
>   1. Fam. Couvrir ou contrôler quelqu'un ou quelque chose. Synon. coiffer. Chaque maison [de la Culture] était chapeautée par un Conseil d'administration. (GILB. 1971)

Cependant en tenant compte d'une remarque dans les commentaires, on peut préférer le verbe  « [coiffer](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=4111099545;) », comme ce dernier est du langage courant alors que « chapeauter » est un terme considéré comme familier (je ne sais pas alors si le TLFi devrait considérer « coiffer » comme un synonyme)

> A. 1. Coiffer qqn (de). 
>   3. Au fig. Être placé à la tête d'un organisme, **exercer son autorité sur**, coordonner les actions
>
> - Coiffer des services; coiffer les différentes activités. Coiffer des entreprises
> - Dès 1941, la France libre avait envoyé dans l'île le capitaine Scamaroni avec mission de préparer l'action. Pendant deux ans, Scamaroni avait fait d'excellent travail, réussissant à coiffer tous les éléments de résistance, afin qu'aucun parti, aucun clan, ne pût monopoliser à son profit l'effort de tous.
>     DE GAULLE, Mémoires de guerre, 1956, p. 141.

Le second concept (« kill ») pourrait être très bien traduit par le verbe « étouffer »<sup>1</sup> ([TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1972004760;)).

> B. P. ext. et au fig.
>   3. a) [Le compl. d'obj. désigne une chose abstr.] **Supprimer quelque chose, l'empêcher de se développer, de se manifester**

- Étouffer un sentiment, la vérité; étouffer une conspiration, l'insurrection, la révolution.
- C'est le propre de l'éducation de développer les facultés, le propre de l'esclavage c'est de les étouffer. (LACLOS, Éduc. femmes, 1803, p. 429)
- Le despotisme étouffe la liberté de la presse (CONSTANT, Esprit conquête, 1813, p. 196)
- ... il a insulté son supérieur. Celui-ci, généreusement, a cherché à étouffer l'affaire. Il a nié ce que chacun savait, mais, comme le scandale était immense, M. Tonski a été envoyé, simple soldat, à la frontière persane. GOBINEAU, Pléiades, 1874, p. 99.
  _ SYNT. *Étouffer l'amour, une ardeur, la compassion, un désir, une émulation, une passion, une pensée, un regret, un remords, un ressentiment, la sensibilité*
  _ *Étouffer qqc. dans l'œuf* [[sens]] L'arrêter avant tout développement

Pour répondre à certaines critiques, je dois dire que je ne pense pas qu'il y ait un cas de redondance dans l'utilisation de « étouffer » après « chapeauter » ou « coiffer » ; il s'agit de deux action différentes bien que la première soit un préliminaire *possible* à la seconde ; dans la première il n'est question que de contrôle, c'est à dire que d'une activité qui suis son cours normalement mais selon certaines règles émises par une entité de contrôle ; dans l'action d'étouffer, même si un contrôle est utilisé abusivement, il s'agit simplement d'une suppression plus ou moins importante de l'activité normale. Donc, de plus que l'on se devrait, lorsqu'en pleine possession des sens des mots, d'identifier cette précédence naturelle des termes à laquelle il est fait allusion ci-dessus, il ne me semble pas du tout y avoir une possibilité d'effet de redondance ou d'identification douteuse.

Un terme de mon cru pour traduire « catch and kill » serait donc « chapeauter et étouffer ».

Cependant plusieurs variantes pourraient se révéler acceptables sinon préférables et même des accessoires utiles:

> - coiffer et étouffer,
> - chapeauter-étouffer,
> - chapeautage et étouffement, chapeautage-étouffement.

Une dernière question soulevée dans un commentaire doit être abordée. Serait-il acceptable de forger le terme « coiffer-étouffer » en vue d'une utilisation en complément de nom dans des syntagmes tels qu'avec le mot « technique » (la technique du chapeauter-étouffer) ?

Je ne sais pas trop ; certains principes sont à observer, comme celui de la minimalisation de la prolifération des formes, celui du choix de la forme bénéficiant de la plus grande adaptabilité dans la syntaxe, celui de la préférence pour les formes courtes, par exemple. Veut-on faire de la forme verbale un nom  (le coiffer-étouffer) ? Préfère-t-on des substantifs (le coiffage-étouffement) ?

Peut-être qu'un idéal serait, sur le modèle anglais, une forme à la fois nominale et verbale et on pourrait écrire alors des chose comme les suivantes ;

- Tout cela ne visait qu'à les coiffer-étouffer.
- La technique du coiffer-étouffer est vieille comme le monde.
- Ils coiffaient-étouffaient leurs efforts depuis longtemps, mais cela a pris fin.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Terme déduit indépendamment de la réponse partielle de  jlliagre  dans les commentaires</sub>